# CheckBox checado conforme string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

Possuo uma string no formato ["0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0"]. Onde 1 representa checado e 0 não checado. Tenho tambem uma grid onde na mesma tenho um checkbox na primeira columa. 
Preciso marcar os checkbox's de acordo com minha string. 
Tentei a principio usando JavaScript, mas não consegui.

C# :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Session["Checados"] = Checados;
.
.
.
}
```

JS e Aspx:

```
 <div class="CentralizarGrid">
    <asp:GridView ID="_gvPontoParada" CssClass="table table-striped grid-table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnDataBound="_gvPontoParada_DataBound" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Código" DataField="Codigo" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descrição" DataField="Descricao" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Endereço" DataField="Endereco" />

        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
 .
 .
 .

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Checados='<%= (Session["Checados"].ToString())%>';
    var check= Checados.split(",");


    function verifica(chk) {
        for(var i = 0; i < check.length; i++)
        {
            if (check[i] == "0")
            {
                document.getElementById(chk).checked = false;
            } else if (check[i] == "1")
            {
                document.getElementById(chk).checked = true;
            }
         }
    }
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você esta o getElementById e não está iterando sobre os diversos checkbox o que acontece é que o checkbox terá sempre o valor igual ao último elemento do vetor Checkados do seu exemplo, seu código teria que ficar na seguinte lógica:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;

    var Checados='<%= (Session["Checados"].ToString())%>';
    var check= Checados.split(","); 

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
         $(this).prop('checked',check[i] == '1' ? true : false); 
         i+=1;
     });
 });
```

Neste exemplo voce percorre todos os imputs do tipo checkbox setando-os como true se a posição do vetor equivalente for igual 1, caso contrário false.